# jQuery Validate addMethod() argument always return true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a custom validation rule, so I am using to check it using addMethod. On rules, I am sending some JSON formatted string to be fetched on the `addMethod`.

```
$.validator.addMethod("chkduplicate", function(value, element, params) {
    console.log(params);
}, "This field value already exists.");
```

Rules should look like:

```
rules: {
  meter_id: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    chkduplicate: '{ "table_name": "users", "fld_name": "user_id"}'
  }
}
```

here `chkduplicate` is the parameter I am sending to addMethod, but when I try to console the params, it always returns true, but it should be `{"table_name": "users", "fld_name": "user_id"}'`

I am using this [plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: why are you trying to JSON.parse `params`? It should already be an object. I see no JSON here. JSON is a textual representation of object data...but your `rules` above looks like an actual JavaScript object literal, to me. And in any case unless you are getting the rules data from somewhere else (e.g. fetching it from a remote server via AJAX) then there would be no reason to need JSON.

Comment: ok, I removed JSON.parse, however, there is no issue with this, I am saying params is the problem

Comment: Your addMethod/validation call looks like what? My guess is the issue is there and not in the code you showed us.

Comment: Just write `chkduplicate: { "table_name": "users", "fld_name": "user_id"}` without the single quotes...there's no need to make it a string as far as I can see

Comment: P.S. I'm guessing this is some kind of custom validation plugin...so it would really help if you tell us what plugin you're using, then we can understand how it's supposed to actually work.

Comment: @ADyson without single Quotes also not working

Comment: "not working" means what? What result _are_ you getting, precisely? Like I said, tell us about the plugin, and tell us what this code is supposed to be doing in reality. We don't really know precisely how the `rules` bit is meant to relate to the "addMethod" bit. It's all slightly unclear. We don't know if you're doing this in the intended way or not.

Comment: @ADyson update the question with plugin i am using

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/75Lxj0om/1/ your code should work fine. (Mine's an example with single-quotes removed, so `params` is always an object, but other than that it's identical to your code (or the bits you showed, at least)). In the console it logs `{table_name: "users", fld_name: "user_id"}`. I tested with Chrome. If you're still having some kind of problem, you'll have to show us enough of your real code so that we can reproduce the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [params](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/#params) 
>   Type: Object
>   parameters specified for the method, e.g. for min: 5, the parameter is 5, for range: [1, 5] it's [1, 5]

Yours is string; try this

```
rules: {
  meter_id: {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    chkduplicate: { "table_name": "users", "fld_name": "user_id"}
  }
}
```

Comment: @JothiKannan Does it still print `true`?

Comment: @JothiKannan see my comment above on the main thread. In theory your code should be fine (and so should the code in this answer). I made a demo to prove it. So if you still have a problem, you'll need to add enough of your real code into the question such that we can reproduce the issue. And/or you could update the demo page with your code, such that it crashes. Then we can see what to fix. At the moment, you haven't given us the key piece of information to make it behave the way you're describing.

Comment: @JothiKannan Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/dubxv0eL/ I have made an example

Edit to make it look like your code